# I want to fetch the values from AdvancedCriteria

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to fetch the values from AdvancedCriteria
 My Code is like this
Now how can I retrieve values from objects ?
How did you get the values from criteria?

```
AdvancedCriteria cr = filterBuilder.getCriteria();
JavaScriptObject jso = cr.getJsObj();
Map map = cr.getValues();
Set keys = map.keySet();
Iterator it = keys.iterator();
while( it.hasNext()){
String key = it.next().toString();
system.out.println("=> "+map.get(key));
}


Out put  
 => AdvancedCriteria               
 => and              
=> [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

To print advanced criteria with inner criterias and advanced criterias you can do something like this:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    AdvancedCriteria crit = filterBuilder.getCriteria();
    printCriteria(crit, 0);
}

public void printCriteria(AdvancedCriteria ac, int level) {
    char[] indentArray = new char[level];
    Arrays.fill(indentArray, '\t');
    String indent = new String(indentArray);

    OperatorId operator = ac.getOperator();
    Criteria[] c = ac.getCriteria();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].isAdvanced()) {
            System.out.println(indent + "(");
            printCriteria(c[i].asAdvancedCriteria(), level + 1);
            System.out.println(indent + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println(indent + 
                c[i].getAttributeAsString("fieldName") + " " +
                c[i].getAttributeAsString("operator") + " " +
                c[i].getAttributeAsString("value"));
    }
    if ((i + 1) < c.length) {
        System.out.println(indent + operator);
    }
}
```